# Is it good to override Activerecord save method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I wanted to override an ActiveRecord save method inorder to bring few things out of the transaction. Is it good idea to override the method?

Comment: no, it's not, you'd rather wrap your save calls

Comment: I just want to know the reason why it is not good because i am little confused should i write a method or override?

Comment: may I know why you want to override?

Comment: It's not good because `save` does fundamental things for the active record necessary for `save`, and you may impact other ActiveRecord methods that depend upon save. Besides, why would you want or need to override it? If you have things you want to do on a `save` then use the callbacks, `:before_save` or `:after_save`

Comment: before_save and after_save will be coming inside the  transaction  i don't want to do any processing inside the transaction because i am doing lot of text processing which intern increases my transaction time and result in db spike and bring your app down

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In most of the cases the answer is no, as there is a number of callbacks you should use instead: before_save, after_save, before_create and after_create. All those callbacks take the record to be saved (or record which has been saved) as an argument, so you can do whatever you want with those. What's more, if any of those callbacks raises exception or returns false, whole transaction is being rolled back.

However: THIS IS RUBY! Which means you can do whatever you want if you really have to. If callbacks are for some reason not sufficient for you, go ahead and override it. Good example of reason to override it would be adding extra argument (not really recommended as might break other methods) or to handle extra options if those are needed (which is quite neat!)

Comment: just because you can do this does not mean that you should. you have to be a really good developer and have really good reason. also changing the way that rails work will present you from upgrading on the next round or version